# Do i have multiple copies of Python installed on my Mac?

Tags: python, easy-install

I get this when i type `"echo $PATH"` in the terminal on my Mac:

```
mattdevlins-MacBook-Pro:~ mattdevlin$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin
mattdevlins-MacBook-Pro:~ mattdevlin$
```

Does this mean I have multiple copies of Python running?

I'm trying to get Scrapy running. Can't figure it out. easy_install is not working.

Comment: You can see which executable is running by typing `which python`. The path is searched from left to right, so in your example your shell will look for python in the 2.7 path before the 3.3 path.

Comment: `which python` will tell you which python is invoked when you type `python` *not* which python is running - for that you need `ps aux`

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean I have multiple copies of Python running?

You almost certainly have multiple versions *installed*, but not necessarily *running*.

For example, I have Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.3 installed on my computer. They co-exist rather happily.

You can launch a specific version by typing `python2.7` or `python3.3` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the `VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION` environmental variable to point to whatever flavor of python you want in OsX. This will invoke the right interpreter if you just run `python` in the command line.

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7 # bash shell
setenv VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION 2.7 # csh or tcsh shells
```